# How to configure the NamespaceMatchingRule(IEnumerable<MatchingInfo>) in unity 2.0 xml configuration file?

Tags: unity-container, aop, policy-injection

How should I pass the `IEnumerable<MatchingInfo>` to one of the overloaded constructor of the `NamespaceMatchingRule` using the unity 2.0 configuration file?